# QuickFixJ custom fields in repeating group

Tags: quickfix, quickfixj

Using QuickFixJ 2.0.1, I'd appreciate some help please, I have been stuck on this for a while now. I am not so familiar with Maven so please bear with me.

I have a DataDictionary containing some custom tags in a `NoQuoteEntries` group (in a `NoQuoteSets` in a `MassQuote`). I cloned the github 2.0.1 and packaged using `mvn package`. I replaced the relevant dictionary `FIX50SP2.xml` and `FIX50SP2.modified.xml` with my custom one of the same name and repackaged.

I can see that the appropriate custom tag classes have been generated as expected and import them, and the custom groups classes have their custom tags in the correct order. What I'm not seeing is the custom tags inside the normal groups' classes. E.g. `NoQuoteEntries` class doesn't contain the custom tags defined in the DD and therefore, when I create a message, the custom tags are put to the end of the groupings rather than the dictionary order. I also cannot `quoteEntry.set(new CustomField(value));` but have to use `quoteEntry.setField(new CustomField(value));`

I could manually create a group of the correct order, but I also need to receive such messages.

There doesn't seem to be a huge amount of information publicly on doing this, but if anyone could state definitively how one creates a `MassQuote` with custom tags inside the `QuotEntryGroup` that would be fantastic please.

Comment: Like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12925850/repeating-group-messages-in-quickfix-c) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31122222/quickfixj-not-honoring-custom-fields-in-a-repeating-group/31126841#31126841) are you sure you’re actually reading the data dictionary?

Comment: It can receive the messages ok using the custom dictionary, but I'm not entirely sure for the rebuilding. I followed those instructions exactly argh. Thanks for flagging those posts though.